# SWIFT 5 - TableView Add loading/Waiting Indicator to the SelectRowAt function - UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**Problem:**
I have a strange bug from Apple where In-App Purchases API from Apple itself takes too long and sometimes Users get confused that nothing is happening in the Background.

**Solution:**
So I need to add a Loading Indicator to my **TableView** ***didSelectRowAt*** function until the response from the In-App is processed in the Background. Is there a way to do this?

See my code snippet below how I do this, I need to add Loading and at End clear the Loading function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//start loading
        switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:  IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .Weekly)
            case 1:  IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .Monthly)
            case 2:  IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .Quarterly)
            case 3:  IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .SemiAnnually)
            case 4:  IAPService.shared.purchase(product: .Annually)
            default: IAPService.shared.restorePurchases()
        }
//end loading
    }
```

What is the best approach to do this? I think this function runs async in the background that i dont have a clear idea on where to put the loading?

Answer (score 0):

in  `SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver` delegate method after getting result you can stop  end loading